# Parallelism of Vectors

Tags: vector-analysis

I know that two lines are parallel if they never intersect each other. 
The conditions for parallel vectors says that if a and b are two vectors then they are parallel if a=kb for k being a scalar. Now if k=1 then a=b implying a is parallel to b that is "a" can be thought of as being parallel to itself. Can one say that every line is also parallel to itself? I think, no. Please share your knowledge with me.

Comment: If *your* definition of parallel lines is that they never intersect each other, then clearly a line is not parallel to itself. It is just a matter of definition

Comment: Is there any other definition of parallel lines?

Comment: As you tagged your question "vector analysis", perhaps it will help to know that two lines are *defined* to be parallel if their direction vectors are a scalar multiple of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course every  line is parallel to itself ( it follows by  the definition of parallelism because we want parallelism is a relation of equivalence).
Notice that if $a$ and $b$ are two vectors and there is k in $R$ with $b$=k $a$, we say that $a$ and $b$ are proportional. Parallelism has a stronger condition: k must be not zero ( because of the consistency of  the definition of  parallelism between vectors).